# Why doesn't "composer update drupal/drupal" work?

Tags: 8, composer

I installed a Drupal 8.2.0 site with `composer create-project drupal/drupal testsite`.

Now I would like to upgrade it to Drupal 8.2.1. However, running `composer update drupal/drupal`  doesn't work. It prints the following error:

> Package "drupal/drupal" listed for update is not installed. Ignoring.

How do I do this? The support is clearly documented in example.gitignore.

```
# Ignore core when managing all of a project's dependencies with Composer
# including Drupal core.
# core
```

So there has to be some way to do this with composer, but how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Think I solved it. I figured that I would need a different root composer.json file that pulled in the drupal package instead of replacing it, but I didn't know how to do so.

Fortunately, someone has already done this and repackaged Drupal in a composer-friendly way: https://github.com/drupal-composer/drupal-project (No stable version yet, apparently.)

By using `composer create-project drupal-composer/drupal-project:8.x-dev --stability dev drupal-dir` I was able to get an install that can be updated with composer.

Comment: The command `composer create-project` uses the requested project as a template for the new project, so in your first attempt,  https://git.drupal.org/project/drupal.git was used as a template for your new project. Using https://github.com/drupal-composer/drupal-project as the template instead, causes Drupal to be one part of the project. In fact, instead of using `drupal/drupal`, it uses `drupal/core` (for the core directory) and `drupal-composer/drupal-scaffold` for the other important files like index.php and .htaccess.

Answer (score 5):

Edit: this is probably not helpful b/c I just re-read your statement and you didn't have the same case as mine where I was coming from an old Drupal 8 install but I will leave this up in case anyone else has this issue and try to see if I can find the specific issue you are having. Sorry.

I had this issue when dealing with a recent update and this was my issue but YMMV so if it doesn't work just let me know.

This may be a problem of that you composer file is set to the old repository listing on composer.org. Recently, Drupal setup their own composer endpoints, one for Drupal 7 and another for Drupal 8. You can read more about that change here: https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/using-composer/using-composer-to-install-drupal-packages-through-drupalorg

This is the command that needs to be ran to swap the repository over the Drupal.org's.

```
$ composer config repositories.0 
$ composer https://packages.drupal.org/8
```

Comment: Interesting error message from that second command: "There are no commands defined in the "https" namespace." I'm really lost now.

Answer (score 3):

The command `composer create-project` clones the requested package, which in this case is https://git.drupal.org/project/drupal.git. At the end of the project creation process, you should be prompted whether you want to remove the existing VCS history. If you answered `n`, you will have a way to update from the upstream drupal repository. Navigate into testsite, and use git to fetch and check out the version of Drupal you want. Then run `composer install` to get the dependencies identified in composer.json and composer.lock of the updated version of Drupal.

Answer (score 3):

On the command line, we had to require drupal core (replace with your version):

```
composer require drupal/core:8.6.3 --update-with-dependencies
```

In the composer.json file under replace we had to remove "drupal/core": "^8.6" so replace looks like:

```
"replace": {

},
```

in our composer.json file now. We then ran:

```
composer update
```

and drupal updated to the latest version.