# Updated to 8.5.1 but front end still says 8.4.4 installed

Tags: updating

I have been going through and updating my drupal sites after the announcement of [CVE-2018-7600](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2018-7600).

All have gone smoothly except for one site that was running Drupal 8.4.4

I updated the site following the [composer/drush method](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/update/update-core-via-composer). This finished successfully.

When I access the sites admin section I still get the warning of a critical update and the Available Updates page states that the currently installed version is still 8.4.4.

I have tried re-running the composer/drush commands, composer returns `Nothing to install or update` and drush returns `No database changes required`. I have also executed `vendor/bin/drush cr` to rebuild the cache.
Navigating to /update.php in the browser returns a green `No pending updates.` page. 
I have also tried logging out and back in, as well as clearing browser cache.

Is there anything else I can do? Is my site updated and just not displaying correctly in the front end, or is the site still vulnerable?

Edit:
Here is the contents of my composer.json file:

```
{
    "name": "drupal/drupal",
    "description": "Drupal is an open source content management platform powering millions of websites and applications.",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "GPL-2.0+",
    "require": {
        "composer/installers": "^1.0.24",
        "wikimedia/composer-merge-plugin": "^1.4",
        "drush/drush": "^9.2"
    },
    "replace": {
        "drupal/core": "^8.5"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "autoloader-suffix": "Drupal8"
    },
    "extra": {
        "_readme": [
            "By default Drupal loads the autoloader from ./vendor/autoload.php.",
            "To change the autoloader you can edit ./autoload.php.",
            "This file specifies the packages.drupal.org repository.",
            "You can read more about this composer repository at:",
            "https://www.drupal.org/node/2718229"
        ],
        "merge-plugin": {
            "include": [
                "core/composer.json"
            ],
            "recurse": false,
            "replace": false,
            "merge-extra": false
        },
        "installer-paths": {
            "core": ["type:drupal-core"],
            "modules/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-module"],
            "profiles/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-profile"],
            "themes/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-theme"],
            "drush/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-drush"],
            "modules/custom/{$name}": ["type:drupal-custom-module"],
            "themes/custom/{$name}": ["type:drupal-custom-theme"]
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Drupal\\Core\\Composer\\": "core/lib/Drupal/Core/Composer"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "pre-autoload-dump": "Drupal\\Core\\Composer\\Composer::preAutoloadDump",
        "post-autoload-dump": [
          "Drupal\\Core\\Composer\\Composer::ensureHtaccess"
        ],
        "post-package-install": "Drupal\\Core\\Composer\\Composer::vendorTestCodeCleanup",
        "post-package-update": "Drupal\\Core\\Composer\\Composer::vendorTestCodeCleanup"
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://packages.drupal.org/8"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: What does `composer show drupal/core` return? It'll output a bunch of stuff, but just looking to see if the 4th line says versions: 8.5.1

Comment: @sonfd it says `[Invalid argument exception] Package drupal/core not found` I will update the OP with the contents of my composer.json file.

Comment: You may need to update to using something like drupal-composer/drupal-project. See: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/217394/why-does-composer-update-drupal-drupal-not-work

Comment: I followed the [top comment](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/217430/84510) and get the same error as the comment there... `There are no commands defined in the https namespace` when trying to run `composer https://packages.drupal.org/8` the output from the first command is: `{"type":"composer","url":"https:\/\/packages.drupal.org\/8"}`