# 8.5.6 Update not being recognized

Tags: updating, composer

I converted a Drupal 7.xx site to Drupal 8.x manually. Updated it to 8.4.5 and tried to use composer to update it to 8.5.6 (Latest stable release). I have the original site as the public_html/drupal site and the 8.4.5 site is at public_html/drupal8/drupal-8.4.5. Composer, then drush seemed to work, but when I take the site out of maintenance mode, log in as admin, "Reports" still say it is at 8.4.5. Commands: `composer update --with-dependencies` and `drush updatedb` (I actually use vendor/drush/drush/drush updatedb) `drush cr` `drush sset system.maintenance_mode 0` `drush cr`

I searched the docs,  found a few suggestions elsewhere, but can't fix this.  The bot on StackOverflow, where I have not gotten any response, suggested I post it here.

Comment: "drupal 8.x manually updated it to 8.4.5" -> this means you've downloaded Drupal as tar/zip to update? Then do the update to 8.5.6 the same way. If you want to update via composer create a composer based Drupal project, for example https://github.com/drupal-composer/drupal-project

Answer (score 1):

Unless you created your site using `composer create-project drupal-composer/drupal-project`, Drupal core is not actually a dependency of your project; instead your composer.json file likely contains the line `"name": "drupal/drupal"`. Effectively, your root composer file *is* the Drupal core package.

In this case you can only upgrade by manually downloading the new release.

See also: [Why does "composer update drupal/drupal" not work?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/217394/why-does-composer-update-drupal-drupal-not-work)

Edit:

If you want to convert an existing D8 site to the composer-based workflow, the following steps should get you most of the way.

- In a different location, use `composer create-project drupal-composer/drupal-project:8.x-dev <my-new-site>` to create the new project. (Confirm the removal of the existing git history, and if you are using version control, use `git init; git add .; git commit` to initialize the new repository.)
- Look at the contrib modules installed in your current site's `modules/` folder, go into the new project, and use `composer require drupal/module1 drupal/module2 [...]` to install them. (Any custom modules should be copied into the folder `./web/modules/custom/` in the new project.)
- Copy the contents of your `sites/` folder into the `./web/sites/` folder of the new project.
- After backing up your database, go into your new project folder, and use `vendor/bin/drush updatedb` or `vendor/bin/drupal upex` to update your database with Drush or Drupal Console (both are installed by default).

At this point, your new project should be ready to serve the site; change your webserver configuration or symlinks to point at `<my-new-site>/web` (the web subdirectory, not the project folder itself).

Comment: So if I throw away the existing project, create a new project with composer, how do I migrate the 7.xx site to 8.5.6?  (I used the migration tool to create the 8.4 site.)

Comment: @Whitekn3 If you have already migrated from D7 to D8.4, it would be easier to reuse that database instead of starting from scratch. I have added some steps for creating a new composer project, and transferring your modules/configuration from the existing D8.4 site over to it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, i found the answer in this discussion [Update Core Using Composer](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2949080#comment-12525004)
Here is the 6 steps, works for me.

1. Removed `drupal/console` package (if it already installed) `composer remove drupal/console`
2. Removed `drupal/console-*` packages (if it already installed) `composer remove drupal/console-core drupal/console-en drupal/console-extend-plugin`.
3. Removed `vendor` folder and `composer.lock` file.
4. Edit `composer.json` : Add `"drupal/core": "8.5.6"` to require section, and remove `replace` section.
5. Execute command `composer update drupal/core --with-dependencies` .
6. Update database by Go to `/update.php` or `drush updb -y`.

Comment: I tried this, but step #1 doesn't work.  If I run "composer remove drupal/console" I get "Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages".  And problem 1 is the same as before: "drupal/core 8.2.x-dev requires symfony/psr-http-message-bridge ..."