# Updating core from 8.4.4 to 8.6.1

Tags: 8, updating, composer

I want to update Drupal from 8.4.4 to 8.6.1. I've tried to follow the steps from [this page](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/update/update-core-via-composer), but without success. When I run this command:

```
composer update drupal/core --with-dependencies
```

I get:

```
 Package "drupal/core" listed for update is not installed. Ignoring.
[Composer\DependencyResolver\SolverProblemsException]
  Problem 1
      - The requested package drupal/coder ^8.3 exists as drupal/coder[8.2.12
  ] but these are rejected by your constraint.
```

I've tried with:

```
composer update drupal/core webflo/drupal-core-require-dev --with-dependencies
```

But, I get the same error. With composer:

```
>composer outdated
alchemy/zippy                         0.4.3              0.4.9
asm89/stack-cors                      1.1.0              1.2.0
behat/mink                            dev-master 04ab7af dev-master d5ee350
behat/mink-browserkit-driver          v1.3.2             1.3.3
chi-teck/drupal-code-generator        1.23.2             1.26.1
composer/installers                   v1.4.0             v1.6.0
consolidation/annotated-command       2.8.3              2.9.1
consolidation/config                  1.0.9              1.1.0
consolidation/log                     1.0.5              1.0.6
consolidation/output-formatters       3.1.13             3.2.1
consolidation/robo                    1.2.2              1.3.1
dflydev/dot-access-configuration      v1.0.2             v1.0.3
doctrine/annotations                  v1.2.7             v1.4.0
doctrine/cache                        v1.6.1             v1.6.2
doctrine/common                       v2.6.2             v2.7.3
drupal/coder                          8.2.12             8.3.0
drush/drush                           9.2.1              9.4.0
egulias/email-validator               1.2.14             2.1.5
fabpot/goutte                         v3.2.1             v3.2.3
guzzlehttp/guzzle                     6.3.0              6.3.3
jcalderonzumba/gastonjs               v1.0.2             v1.2.0
jcalderonzumba/mink-phantomjs-driver  v0.3.1             v0.3.3
paragonie/random_compat               v2.0.10            v2.0.17
phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock     2.0.4              3.3.2
phpoffice/phpspreadsheet              1.1.0              1.4.0
phpspec/prophecy                      v1.7.0             1.8.0
phpunit/php-code-coverage             2.2.4              4.0.8
phpunit/php-file-iterator             1.4.2              1.4.5
phpunit/php-token-stream              1.4.11             1.4.12
phpunit/phpunit                       4.8.36             5.7.27
phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects          2.3.8              3.4.4
psr/simple-cache                      1.0.0              1.0.1
psy/psysh                             v0.9.5             v0.9.8
sebastian/environment                 1.3.8              2.0.0
sebastian/exporter                    1.2.2              2.0.0
sebastian/recursion-context           1.0.5              2.0.0
sebastian/version                     1.0.6              2.0.1
squizlabs/php_codesniffer             2.8.1              3.3.2
stack/builder                         v1.0.4             v1.0.5
symfony-cmf/routing                   1.4.1              2.0.3
symfony/class-loader                  v3.2.14            v3.4.15
symfony/config                        v3.2.14            v3.4.15
symfony/console                       v3.2.14            v3.4.15
symfony/css-selector                  v3.2.14            v3.4.15
symfony/dependency-injection          v3.2.14            v3.4.15
symfony/event-dispatcher              v3.2.14            v3.4.15
symfony/http-foundation               v3.2.14            v3.4.15
symfony/http-kernel                   v3.2.14            v3.4.15
symfony/phpunit-bridge                v3.2.14            v4.1.4
symfony/process                       v3.2.14            v3.4.15
symfony/psr-http-message-bridge       v1.0.2             v1.1.0
symfony/routing                       v3.2.14            v3.4.15
symfony/serializer                    v3.2.14            v3.4.15
symfony/translation                   v3.2.14            v3.4.15
symfony/validator                     v3.2.14            v3.4.15
symfony/yaml                          v3.2.14            v3.4.15
```

But I tried to update this dependencies but they are locked. I think I have to change composer.json to unlock some configuration, but I'm not sure what should I do.
What is the right way to update Drupal Core?
Thanks.

Comment: What does your Drupal composer.json say about Drupal core version? You do have some instructions at the bottom of that article, especially the linked article that updates to 8.5. How did you install this Drupal? It may be you always need to use the (second) webflo command.

Comment: What happens if you just run an unconditional composer update? That will update everything it can but you can always lock down certain modules/dependencies if the latest version causes a problem.

Comment: Check this out this 6 steps works for me [8.5.6 Update not being recognized](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/267630/8-5-6-update-not-being-recognized/267725#267725)

Comment: As Berdir said, I think my installation didn't use composer. I tried to composerize using the module, but without success. At the end, I had to update manually. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

Missed the "Package "drupal/core" listed for update is not installed."

What that means is that you did not install this based on https://github.com/drupal-composer/drupal-project, which simply means that these instructions are not for you.

You either need to update that by getting the latest tarball and then re-adding your additional dependencies, or, recommended, switch now to a drupal-project based build, which is the de-facto standard.

I only had a quick look at it, but https://www.jeffgeerling.com/blog/2018/converting-non-composer-drupal-codebase-use-composer looks like a detailed/comprehensive blog post on how to do that.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It put me in the way. I read about composerize my drupal installation, and I tried with this project [link](https://github.com/grasmash/composerize-drupal). But without success. At the end I updated the core manually.