# Error updating modules with composer

Tags: updating, composer

I'm trying to update a module with composer.
This is the command (but it the same if I try to update another module):

```
composer update --with-dependencies drupal/geofield_map
```

This is the output of composer prohibits:

```
drupal/drupal  dev-master  requires  drupal/geofield_map (^2.10)
```

I obtain these error when I try to update:

```
Problem 1
    - don't install drupal/core 8.6.5|remove drupal/drupal dev-master
    - remove drupal/drupal dev-master|remove drupal/core 8.6.5
    - don't install drupal/core 8.6.5|remove drupal/drupal dev-master
    - Installation request for drupal/drupal dev-master -> satisfiable by drupal/drupal[dev-master].
    - Installation request for drupal/core (locked at 8.6.5, required as ^8.6) -> satisfiable by drupal/core[8.6.5].
```

I'm not a "composer expert" and I'm not able to solve it.

Here is my composer.json

```
{
    "name": "drupal/drupal",
    "description": "Drupal is an open source content management platform powering millions of websites and applications.",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "GPL-2.0-or-later",
    "require": {
        "composer/installers": "^1.0.24",
        "wikimedia/composer-merge-plugin": "^1.4",
        "drupal/search_api_solr": "^2.0",
        "drupal/address": "~1.0",
        "mpdf/mpdf": "^7.0",
        "drupal/geofield_map": "^2.10",
        "drupal/console": "~1.0",
        "swiftmailer/swiftmailer": "5.4.5",
        "lullabot/amp": "^1.0.0",
        "drupal/csv_serialization": "^1.4",
        "drupal/core": "^8.6",
        "webflo/drupal-core-strict": "^8.6"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "autoloader-suffix": "Drupal8"
    },
    "extra": {
        "_readme": [
            "By default Drupal loads the autoloader from ./vendor/autoload.php.",
            "To change the autoloader you can edit ./autoload.php.",
            "This file specifies the packages.drupal.org repository.",
            "You can read more about this composer repository at:",
            "https://www.drupal.org/node/2718229"
        ],
        "merge-plugin": {
            "include": [
                "core/composer.json"
            ],
            "recurse": true,
            "replace": false,
            "merge-extra": false
        },
        "installer-paths": {
            "core": ["type:drupal-core"],
            "modules/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-module"],
            "profiles/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-profile"],
            "themes/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-theme"],
            "drush/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-drush"],
            "modules/custom/{$name}": ["type:drupal-custom-module"],
            "themes/custom/{$name}": ["type:drupal-custom-theme"]
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Drupal\\Core\\Composer\\": "core/lib/Drupal/Core/Composer"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "pre-autoload-dump": "Drupal\\Core\\Composer\\Composer::preAutoloadDump",
        "post-autoload-dump": "Drupal\\Core\\Composer\\Composer::ensureHtaccess",
        "post-package-install": "Drupal\\Core\\Composer\\Composer::vendorTestCodeCleanup",
        "post-package-update": "Drupal\\Core\\Composer\\Composer::vendorTestCodeCleanup",
        "drupal-phpunit-upgrade-check": "Drupal\\Core\\Composer\\Composer::upgradePHPUnit",
        "drupal-phpunit-upgrade": "@composer update phpunit/phpunit --with-dependencies --no-progress",
        "phpcs": "phpcs --standard=core/phpcs.xml.dist --runtime-set installed_paths $($COMPOSER_BINARY config vendor-dir)/drupal/coder/coder_sniffer --",
        "phpcbf": "phpcbf --standard=core/phpcs.xml.dist --runtime-set installed_paths $($COMPOSER_BINARY config vendor-dir)/drupal/coder/coder_sniffer --"
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://packages.drupal.org/8"
        }
    ]
}
```

[EDIT]
If I try to replace "drupal/core": "^8.6" with "drupal/core": "8.6.5" I obtain:

```
 Problem 1
    - drupal/core 8.2.x-dev requires symfony/psr-http-message-bridge v0.2 -> satisfiable by symfony/psr-http-message-bridge[v0.2] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.2.0|remove drupal/drupal dev-master
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.2.0-beta1|remove drupal/drupal dev-master
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.2.0-beta2|remove drupal/drupal dev-master
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.2.0-beta3|remove drupal/drupal dev-master
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.2.0-rc1|remove drupal/drupal dev-master
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.2.0-rc2|remove drupal/drupal dev-master
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.2.1|remove drupal/drupal dev-master
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.2.2|remove drupal/drupal dev-master
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.2.3|remove drupal/drupal dev-master
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.2.4|remove drupal/drupal dev-master
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.2.5|remove drupal/drupal dev-master
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.2.6|remove drupal/drupal dev-master
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.2.7|remove drupal/drupal dev-master
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.2.8|remove drupal/drupal dev-master
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.2.x-dev|remove drupal/drupal dev-master
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.3.0|remove drupal/drupal dev-master
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.3.0-alpha1|remove drupal/drupal dev-master
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.3.0-beta1|remove drupal/drupal dev-master
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.3.0-rc1|remove drupal/drupal dev-master
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.3.0-rc2|remove drupal/drupal dev-master
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.3.1|remove drupal/drupal dev-master
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.3.2|remove drupal/drupal dev-master
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.3.3|remove drupal/drupal dev-master
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.3.4|remove drupal/drupal dev-master
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.3.5|remove drupal/drupal dev-master
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.3.6|remove drupal/drupal dev-master
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.3.7|remove drupal/drupal dev-master
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.3.8|remove drupal/drupal dev-master
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.3.9|remove drupal/drupal dev-master
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.3.x-dev|remove drupal/drupal dev-master
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.4.0|remove drupal/drupal dev-master
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.4.0-alpha1|remove drupal/drupal dev-master
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.4.0-beta1|remove drupal/drupal dev-master
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.4.0-rc1|remove drupal/drupal dev-master
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.4.0-rc2|remove drupal/drupal dev-master
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.4.1|remove drupal/drupal dev-master
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.4.2|remove drupal/drupal dev-master
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.4.3|remove drupal/drupal dev-master
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.4.4|remove drupal/drupal dev-master
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.4.5|remove drupal/drupal dev-master
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.4.6|remove drupal/drupal dev-master
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.4.7|remove drupal/drupal dev-master
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.4.8|remove drupal/drupal dev-master
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.4.x-dev|remove drupal/drupal dev-master
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.5.0|remove drupal/drupal dev-master
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.5.0-alpha1|remove drupal/drupal dev-master
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.5.0-beta1|remove drupal/drupal dev-master
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.5.0-rc1|remove drupal/drupal dev-master
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.5.1|remove drupal/drupal dev-master
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.5.2|remove drupal/drupal dev-master
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.5.3|remove drupal/drupal dev-master
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.5.4|remove drupal/drupal dev-master
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.5.5|remove drupal/drupal dev-master
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.5.6|remove drupal/drupal dev-master
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.5.7|remove drupal/drupal dev-master
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.5.8|remove drupal/drupal dev-master
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.5.x-dev|remove drupal/drupal dev-master
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.6.0|remove drupal/drupal dev-master
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.6.0-alpha1|remove drupal/drupal dev-master
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.6.0-beta1|remove drupal/drupal dev-master
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.6.0-beta2|remove drupal/drupal dev-master
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.6.0-rc1|remove drupal/drupal dev-master
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.6.1|remove drupal/drupal dev-master
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.6.2|remove drupal/drupal dev-master
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.6.3|remove drupal/drupal dev-master
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.6.4|remove drupal/drupal dev-master
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.6.5|remove drupal/drupal dev-master
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.6.x-dev|remove drupal/drupal dev-master
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.7.x-dev|remove drupal/drupal dev-master
    - don't install drupal/core 8.3.x-dev|remove drupal/drupal dev-master
    - don't install drupal/core 8.4.x-dev|remove drupal/drupal dev-master
    - don't install drupal/core 8.5.x-dev|remove drupal/drupal dev-master
    - don't install drupal/core 8.6.5|remove drupal/drupal dev-master
    - don't install drupal/core 8.6.x-dev|remove drupal/drupal dev-master
    - don't install drupal/core 8.7.x-dev|remove drupal/drupal dev-master
    - remove drupal/drupal dev-master|remove drupal/core 8.6.5
    - don't install drupal/core 8.6.5|remove drupal/drupal dev-master
    - Installation request for drupal/drupal dev-master -> satisfiable by drupal/drupal[dev-master].
    - Installation request for drupal/core-render ^8.2 -> satisfiable by drupal/core[8.2.x-dev, 8.3.x-dev, 8.4.x-dev, 8.5.x-dev, 8.6.5, 8.6.x-dev, 8.7.x-dev], drupal/core-render[8.2.0, 8.2.0-beta1, 8.2.0-beta2, 8.2.0-beta3, 8.2.0-rc1, 8.2.0-rc2, 8.2.1, 8.2.2, 8.2.3, 8.2.4, 8.2.5, 8.2.6, 8.2.7, 8.2.8, 8.2.x-dev, 8.3.0, 8.3.0-alpha1, 8.3.0-beta1, 8.3.0-rc1, 8.3.0-rc2, 8.3.1, 8.3.2, 8.3.3, 8.3.4, 8.3.5, 8.3.6, 8.3.7, 8.3.8, 8.3.9, 8.3.x-dev, 8.4.0, 8.4.0-alpha1, 8.4.0-beta1, 8.4.0-rc1, 8.4.0-rc2, 8.4.1, 8.4.2, 8.4.3, 8.4.4, 8.4.5, 8.4.6, 8.4.7, 8.4.8, 8.4.x-dev, 8.5.0, 8.5.0-alpha1, 8.5.0-beta1, 8.5.0-rc1, 8.5.1, 8.5.2, 8.5.3, 8.5.4, 8.5.5, 8.5.6, 8.5.7, 8.5.8, 8.5.x-dev, 8.6.0, 8.6.0-alpha1, 8.6.0-beta1, 8.6.0-beta2, 8.6.0-rc1, 8.6.1, 8.6.2, 8.6.3, 8.6.4, 8.6.5, 8.6.x-dev, 8.7.x-dev].
```

Comment: which version of drupal you have (actual one)?

Comment: I've 8.6.5, latest stable

Comment: Ok, try with `composer update --with-dependencies  'drupal/geofield_map:^2.23'`

Comment: I obtain:
 Problem 1
    - don't install drupal/core 8.6.5|remove drupal/drupal dev-master
    - remove drupal/drupal dev-master|remove drupal/core 8.6.5
    - don't install drupal/core 8.6.5|remove drupal/drupal dev-master
    - Installation request for drupal/drupal dev-master -> satisfiable by drupal/drupal[dev-master].
    - Installation request for drupal/core (locked at 8.6.5, required as ^8.6) -> satisfiable by drupal/core[8.6.5].

Comment: Try with the steps of my answer on this question https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/267630/8-5-6-update-not-being-recognized/267725#267725

Comment: it works but remain errors.. If I try to add with composer a new module I obtain the first error of my post

Comment: I tend to use `composer require drupal/geofield_map:VERSION` over doing `composer update` anymore.

Comment: `drupal/core 8.2.x-dev requires ...` whats going on with that output?

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same issue as you -- really bizarre. Instead of using composer update, I removed the module I was trying to update from my composer.json and ran composer require again instead for the newest version of the module (in your case this would be `composer require  drupal/geofield_map:^2.10`).

I also had to remove the merge-plugin section of my composer.json (actually this may fix the issue without worrying about manually re-requiring the module).

Comment: removing merge-plugin section helped

Answer (score -2):

1. You can use the administrative interface:
   ==> admin/reports/updates/update
2. Use drush
3. Use the composer command : `composer update` ==> will update all your librairies

Comment: Doing a blanket `composer update` is ill advised unless specific versions of modules are listed in composer.json. I certainly wouldn't want 50 other modules to update when I am targeting one.

Comment: I already mentioned that composer updat will update all the modules

Comment: Updating everything when you only want to update one module is extremely risky. You take one change and turn it into hundreds.