# Error guzzlehttp/guzzle ^6.3 -> no matching package found when update from 8.7.9 to 8.8.1

Tags: 8, updating, composer

When i tried to update my project using composer from `8.7.9` to `8.8.1` i get the following error:

Command:

```
composer update drupal/core --with-dependencies
```

> [Composer\DependencyResolver\SolverProblemsException]
>     Problem 1
>         - Installation request for drupal/core 8.8.1 -> satisfiable by drupal/core[8.8.1].
>         - drupal/core 8.8.1 requires guzzlehttp/guzzle ^6.3 -> no matching package found.
>       Problem 2 .
>         - drupal/core 8.8.1 requires guzzlehttp/guzzle ^6.3 -> no matching package found.
>         - drupal/ultimate_cron 2.x-dev requires drupal/core ^8.5 -> satisfiable by drupal/core[8.8.1].
>         - Installation request for drupal/ultimate_cron ^2.0 -> satisfiable by drupal/ultimate_cron[2.x-dev].
>
> Potential causes:
>      - A typo in the package name .
>      - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting . 
>        see https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability for more details.
>      - It's a private package and you forgot to add a custom repository to find it

Any ideas ?

Comment: Run `composer clear-cache` and try again

Comment: I have tried, the same result!

Comment: Maybe try `composer update drupal/core guzzlehttp/guzzle --with-dependencies`

Comment: I have tried it too, the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just to remove the `vendor` Folder it works now:
For the complete steps see [8.5.6 Update not being recognized](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/267630/8-5-6-update-not-being-recognized?answertab=active#tab-top) .